# Redirect requests for static files in a local directory to MVC Action

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

The problem is a local directory containing sub-directories each with multiple zip files. We cannot change the links external to the system but must now reroute them to S3. The application is built on ASP.NET MVC 5.

Proposed Solution (what I am trying):
To capture all inbound requests for /directory/subdirectory/xyz.zip and redirect them to an MVC controller action to send them the proper file from S3.

Structure:

```
root/DIRECTORY/*subdirectories/*.zip
```

Example urls:

```
www.somewhere.com/Packages/{Guid}/{Guid}-IDENTIFIER.zip
```

1. added new controller Packages
2. added the following route

```
routes.MapRoute(
               "RedirectDownloads",
                "{controller}/{key}/{zip}",
                new { controller = "Packages", action = "Index"},
                new
                {
                    key = @"[{|\(]?[0-9a-fA-F]{8}[-]?([0-9a-fA-F]{4}[-]?){3}[0-9a-fA-F]{12}[\)|}]?",
                    zip = @"[a-fA-F0-9]{8}(?:-[a-fA-F0-9]{4}){3}-[a-fA-F0-9]{12}\-.*\.zip"
                }
                );
```

This obviously isn't hit due to these being static files on the file system so I also tried the following under ..

```
<add name="Zips-ISAPI-Integrated-4.0" path="*.zip" verb="GET" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
```

But this causing IIS to throw an error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your web.config, find the `<handlers/ >` tag

Add this:

```
<add name="zipThingy" path="*.zip" verb="GET" type="MikesProject.ZipThingy"/>
```

Then add this class:

```
namespace MikesProject
{
    public class ZipThingy: IHttpHandler, IReadOnlySessionState
    {
        public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
        {
            var request = context.Request;
            var response = context.Response;
        }
    }
}
```

Then either:
1. Return a straight redirect to the S3 URL, like this: `response.RedirectPermanent("http://S3.URL.ZIP");`
2. You put your logic into `ProcessRequest` instead of your controller, which will download the zip from S3 and return the file, or
2. Have `response` return a redirect to your controller, passing the relevant data. You can get the filename like this: `Path.GetFileName(context.Request.PhysicalPath)`

Comment: Thanks Rob. My brain was not working last night and this was just what I needed to get me on track!

Comment: @Mike No worries, glad it helped :)